# Is there any class that handles data binding for RecyclerView ViewHolders?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I've been looking for a convenient way to outsource some of the data binding code within the `RecyclerView.Adapter`. I was looking at the following tutorial: https://www.journaldev.com/12372/android-recyclerview-example which seems to be working quite nicely for 2-3 different `ViewHolders`. But as soon as the number of different ViewHolders increases (let's say 10 or more), the method `onBindViewHolder` will massively explode in size. Therefore I was looking for a way to outsource this data binding part from the adapter. Since I do not want to reinvent the wheel, I was looking for a maybe already existent solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case there is no existent solution for this problem, I came up with the following idea:

First create a subclass of `ViewHolder` and add another abstract method `bindData`

```java
abstract class DataBindingViewHolder<T> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

         DataBindingViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
             super(itemView);
         }

         abstract void bindData(T t);
    }
```

Secondly, create as many subclasses of this class as you need. For example these two:

```java
class ItemViewHolder extends DataBindingViewHolder<Item> {

    TextView itemNameTextView;
    TextView itemDescriptionTextView;


    ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        // TODO init fields here
    }

    @Override
    void bindData(Item item) {
        String itemName = item.getName();
        String itemDescription = item.getDescription();

        itemNameTextView.setText(itemName);
        itemDescriptionTextView.setText(itemDescription);
    }
}
```

```java
class ExtendedItemViewHolder extends DataBindingViewHolder<Item> {

    TextView itemNameTextView;
    TextView itemDescriptionTextView;
    TextView itemPriceTextView;
    ImageView itemPreviewImageView;


    ExtendedItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        // TODO init fields here
    }

    @Override
    void bindData(Item item) {
        String itemName = item.getName();
        String itemDescription = item.getDescription();
        String itemPrice = item.getPrice();
        Bitmap itemPreviewImage = item.getImage();

        itemNameTextView.setText(itemName);
        itemDescriptionTextView.setText(itemDescription);
        itemPriceTextView.setText(itemPrice);
        itemPreviewImageView.setImageBitmap(itemPreviewImage);
    }
}
```

Lastly, the `onBindViewHolder` method will now simply look like this:

```java
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataBindingViewHolder<Item> viewHolder, int i) {
        Item item = itemList.get(i);
        viewHolder.bindData(item);
    }
```

Keep in mind: You still have to override the `getItemViewType` method, depending on the data you need to provide.